# Why can't I have a JSX comment inside an element tag?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm following the common pattern of breaking multi-attribute tags on to multiple lines, eg.

```
<div
  className="foo"
  style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
/>
```

I would like to add a comment inside that declaration, eg.

```
<div
  className="foo"
  {/* This is only temporary */}
  style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
/>
```

However the above syntax doesn't work; I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ... (45:96)
```

(pointing to the closing `}` in `temporary */}`.)
  Is it possible to add a comment inside a tag in JSX, and if so what syntax should I use?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can comment inside JSX tags like so:

```
<div
  className="foo"
  /* This is only temporary */
  style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
/>
```

Note: there are no "{" and "}"

[a live example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apollotang/7s0avpzh/)

I remember read this in [the official document few years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305161941/https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#comments), but after they rewrite the document, I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't marked as the correct answer, this is how you do comments inside jsx tags.

Comment: A single line comment (`//`) is also possible.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "you can't", but there are various ways to fake it. The simplest, I think, is to piggy-back on another value:

```
<img
  alt={"settings link"
  /* This is just temporary */}
  src="http://www.example.com/foo.jpg"
/>
```

It's a bit less than optimally clear, but all we've done is moved the brace up one line. That converts the "settings link" from a HTML-esque JSX value to a Javascript expression, which just happens to have a comment.

It does have the advantage that it ties the comment to the individual attribute, rather than the tag as a whole. I think that's clearer; if you really wanted to comment on the tag you'd do better to move it to the top.

If your goal was to comment out some attribute, yeah, that's a little obscure. But it should be clear enough to un-comment when you get around to it.

Comment: Note that @apollo's answer below is now the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing props and children. When you do:

```
<div
  className="foo"
  {/* bar */}
>
```

You are attempting to use an inline JSX expression *as if you were passing props* inside the opening tag, this is NOT allowed. When you have an element, the opening tag can *only contain deconstructed objects or `prop=value`* values hence the reason it expects `...` to deconstruct an object with props and values, for example:

```
const props = {
    className: "foo"
}

<div {...props}>
```

You can't comment inside the tag because the tag doesn't allow for inline JSX expressions. JSX expressions are only allowed as children:

```
{/* bar */}
<div
  className="foo"
>
```

In this example, the expression is not inside the opening tag of an element and allowed.

Comment: So long story short, it's impossible to add any sort of comment inside a JSX tag?  In other words, there's no alternate syntax that will work for props?

Comment: @machineghost Nope, at least not that I know of. JSX tags only support valid keys and values as props or deconstructed objects, nothing more.

Comment: @machineghost Anyways, I would actually prefer commenting at the top than inside the props even if you could - it would be easier to read IMO. You could always mock props and set a useless prop for the comment but I would do it at the top.